# Angular 2: How retrieve the changes that are done to an injected html?

Tags: angularjs, object, render, inject

I've inject HTML from an object that I created and than using a pipe I by pass the angular security to display input fields, text area etc..

I am inject an input field, some text and a `<p contenteditable="true"> change me </p>` that you can edit.

3) How to than track changes when user is updating the inner of   and push it back to the object ?

**If the user changes the HTML inside `[innerHTML]="item.htmldata"` is there a way to track it?**

```
obj: Array<any> = [
  { htmldata:  '<div> <strong> There should be a input field below </strong> <input type="text" value="search" /></div>' },
  { htmldata:  '<div> <strong> me to, how are you </strong></div>'}
]
```

I am running through an `ngFor` loop and binding the data through angular [innerHTML]="item.htmldata"

```
<div *ngFor="let item of obj" >

 {{item.htmldata | json }}
 <div [innerHTML]="item.htmldata"  | safeHtml></div>
 <br />
 <hr>
</div>


**SafeHTML pipe**
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';


DomSanitizer
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    //return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ADeAEz81a07Cl2yrDGqQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `sanitizedHtmlProperty` by this code.

**Sample Code**

```
public get sanitizedHtmlProperty() : SafeHtml {
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._originalHtmlProperty);
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eqZ9KoePKTotXfn1OSrl?p=preview)

**Edit**

You can use `Blur` and `keyup`

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
selector: '[contenteditableModel]',
host: {
    '(blur)': 'onEdit()',
    '(keyup)': 'onEdit()'
}
})

export class ContentEditableDirective implements OnChanges {
@Input('contenteditableModel') model: any;
@Output('contenteditableModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();

constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
) {
    console.log('ContentEditableDirective.constructor');
}

ngOnChanges(changes) {
    console.log('ContentEditableDirective.ngOnChanges');
    console.log(changes);
    if (changes.model.isFirstChange())
        this.refreshView();
}

onEdit() {
    console.log('ContentEditableDirective.onEdit');
    var value = this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerText
    this.update.emit(value)
}

private refreshView() {
    console.log('ContentEditableDirective.refreshView');
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.textContent = this.model
}
}
```

[Reference](https://www.namekdev.net/2016/01/two-way-binding-to-contenteditable-element-in-angular-2/)

**Edit 2**

Here is code for tracking changes [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMRx7GgqZtX1q70MsMYr?p=preview)

Comment: How to than track changes when user is updating the inner of and push it back to the object ?

Comment: did you get the chance to get a plunker up also?

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs Please check plunker url